# PHP чистка URL через функцию

Tags: php, get

День добрый.

На сайте чистку URL делаю так:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val){
    if($key != 'pNum' AND $key !='itemCatId' AND $key != 'removeItem'){
        $uriN .= "{$key}={$val}&";
    }
}
```

Пробовал сделать через функцию:

```
function ClUrl ($cond) {
$cUrl = '?';

foreach($_GET as $key => $val){
    if($cond){
        $cUrl .= "{$key}={$val}&";
    }
}

return $cUrl;
}
```

Далее вот таким образом передавал условие в функцию:

```
$imgUrl = ClUrl("$key != 'pNum' AND $key !='itemCatId' AND $key != 'removeItem'");
```

Пробовал и так:

```
$imgUrl = ClUrl($key != 'pNum' AND $key !='itemCatId' AND $key != 'removeItem');
```

Не работает.

Я так понимаю, из-за того что `$key` определяется еще до вызова функции?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, при любом раскладе через передачу параметров функции не работает очистка урла, так что сделал вот так:

```
$cleanUri = '?';
$clArray = array('itemCatId','removeItem','bill');
foreach($_GET as $key => $val){
    if(!in_array($key,$clArray)){$cleanUri .= "{$key}={$val}&";}
}
```

Comment: @Cone учтите, что такая сборка строки запроса не выполняет URL-кодирование значений. Т.е. если среди значений `$val` есть, напр., символ "&", всё полетит в тар-тарарары.

Answer (score 1):

Значит, вы хотите из всех переданных параметров убрать определённые. Это можно сделать так:

```
$banned = array( "noone", "hackme"); // перечислить запрещённые
$cleanURL = '?' . http_build_query( array_diff_key( $_GET, array_combine( $banned, array_pad( array(), count( $banned), 0))));
```

Или, если не выпендриваться в две строчки, то по шагам:

```
$banned = array( "noone", "hackme"); // перечислить запрещённые
$values = array_pad( array(), count( $banned), 0);  // массив из 0 по числу запрещённых
$assoc_ban = array_combine( $banned, $values);      // ассоц. массив с ключами из запр.
$exclude_banned = array_diff_key( $_GET, $assoc_ban); // из $_GET убрали все запр.
$cleanURL = '?' . http_build_query( $exclude_banned); // собрали строку запроса
```

---

А в первый раз я понял с точностью до наоборот: если вы хотите из всех переданных параметров сформировать запрос содержащий только несколько избранных параметров, то можно использовать [`filter_input_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input-array.php):

```
$args = array(
    'pNum'       => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'itemCatId'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'removeItem' => FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
);
$params = filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, $args, FALSE);
$imgUrl = "?" . http_build_query( $params);
```

(Не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вместо `AND` использовать `&&`.

касательно `$key` - в него попадет индекс массива. так что он определяется еще на этапе обращения к скрипту. допустим вы передаете строку `?var1=value1&var2=value2` в таком случае на первом шаге foreach в $key у вас будет `var1`, в `val` - `value1`, на втором - в $key у вас будет `var2`, в `val` - `value2`